# Why is Nokogiri not finding this img tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri

I'm starting with:

```
text = "Dear Harry,<div>Hope all is well with you in the current strange times, and that you are not suffering too much in isolation.Look what I just got delivered:<img class=\"small\" src=\"s\"></div>"
```

I parsed it into a Nokogiri fragment:

```
f = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(text)
```

However, both of the following return the empty list:

```
f.xpath('//img')

f.xpath('img')
```

and I don't know why.

However, I can find the img tag like this:

```
 f.xpath('*')[0].xpath('img')

 => [#<Nokogiri::XML::Element:0x3fd63d7731cc name="img" attributes=[#<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd63d772c68 name="class" value="small">, #<Nokogiri::XML::Attr:0x3fd63d772c54 name="src" value="s">]>]
```

I thought `'//img'` was meant to do a recursive search?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I avoid XPath for the most part. CSS is more readable and works for most of the things we do:

```
require 'nokogiri'

text = 'foo<div>bar<img class="small" src="s"></div>'
fragment = Nokogiri::HTML::DocumentFragment.parse(text)
fragment.at('img').to_html
# => "<img class=\"small\" src=\"s\">"
```

Or, instead, use regular parsing into a full document, then either CSS or XPath will work:

```
doc = Nokogiri::HTML(text)
doc.at('img').to_html # => "<img class=\"small\" src=\"s\">"
doc.at('//img').to_html # => "<img class=\"small\" src=\"s\">"
```

`//...` in XPath is a recursive search, it starts at the top of the document and descends.

Answer (score 0):

It appears to be an open issue that fragments don't find elements with the expected xpath expression...

https://github.com/sparklemotion/nokogiri/issues/572

but this will work...

```
f.xpath('.//img')
```